# How to sort list items to default order from ascending or descending order in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, xcode, arraylist, swiftui

I'm newbie to SwiftUI. I want to sort list items to default order. I can able to sort ascending or descending order but not default order. Please help me in this regard.

Here is my ascending and descending order code.

**Ascending order:**

```
items.sort {(lhs, rhs) -> Bool in
     return lhs.name < rhs.name
}
```

**Descending order:**

```
items.sort {(lhs, rhs) -> Bool in
     return lhs.name > rhs.name
}
```

**Default order..?**

CODE:

```
@State var items: [Names] = itemsName
@State var toggleItems: Int = 0
ForEach() { item in 
NavigationLink(destination: FormulasView()) {
   VStack {
         NameRowView(items: item)
       }
    }
}
.onChange(of: sortListItems) {_ in
    if(toggleItems == 1) {
        items.sort {(lhs, rhs) -> Bool in
           return lhs.name < rhs.name
      }
    } else if(toggleItems == 2) {
        items.sort {(lhs, rhs) -> Bool in
           return lhs.name > rhs.name
      }
    } else {
        items.sort {(lhs, rhs) -> Bool in
           return lhs.name == rhs.name
      }
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is "default order"? What is the "default order" for, say, `["bob", "mark", "jerry", "adam"]`?

Comment: @Sweeper Yes, i want to set back to default oder after selecting ascending or descending order.

Comment: @Ashok **what do you mean by default order**? Do you mean how the list originally was? If so, you would have to introduce a second variable.

Comment: Okay I think I get what you mean. How about using `sorted` instead of `sort` so you get new arrays? Then you can just use `items` by itself (without calling anything on it) for the default order.

Comment: @Sweeper, Yes. Explanation: After app opens the list is in original order like - `["bob", "mark", "jerry", "adam"]`. After selecting Ascending list will be `["adam", "bob", "jerry", "mark"]` After selecting Descending list will be `["mark", "jerry", "bob", "adam"]` Then I want to set to original list order like what will be on app opens `["bob", "mark", "jerry", "adam"]` from ascending or descending order list. Could you please tell me how can I do it with example.

Comment: Please show a [mcve] of how you are using the sorted list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `sort` will sort the collection **in place**. That is the original array is changed.
When you use `sorted(by:...)` the original array is **not** changed.

Here is some code that shows how you can get the original `default` array, after sorting it.

```
 let items = ["Kofi", "Abena", "Peter", "Kweku", "Akosua"]
 let descent = items.sorted(by: > )
 let ascent = items.sorted(by: < )
 
 print("items sorted > : \(descent) ")
 print("items sorted < : \(ascent) ")
 print("items sorted default : \(items) ")
```

EDIT-1:

more example code to show how to use `sorted(by: ...)`

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var items = ["Kofi", "Abena", "Peter", "Kweku"]
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("sorted descending")
            List (items.sorted(by: > ), id: \.self) { item in
                Text(item)
            }
            Spacer()
            Text("sorted ascending")
            List (items.sorted(by: < ), id: \.self) { item in
                Text(item)
            }
            Spacer()
            Text("original")
            List (items, id: \.self) { item in
                Text(item)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

More example code, in view of your new question:

```
    struct ContentView: View {
    @State var items = ["Kofi", "Abena", "Peter", "Kweku"]
    @State var toggleItems: Int = 0
    
    var itemsSorted: [String] {
        if (toggleItems == 1) {
            return items.sorted(by: < )
        } else if (toggleItems == 2) {
            return items.sorted(by: > )
        }
        return items  // original
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack {
                Button("descending") { toggleItems = 1}
                Button("ascending") { toggleItems = 2}
                Button("original") { toggleItems = 0}
            }.buttonStyle(.bordered)
            List (itemsSorted, id: \.self) { item in
                NavigationLink(destination: Text("FormulasView")) {
                    // NameRowView(items: item)
                    Text(item)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. Showing error like `Cannot use instance member 'items' within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available` at 2 places `descent` and `ascent`

Comment: @Ashok ...and that is exactly why I told you to show a [mcve] of your code.

Comment: put all this code in `.onAppear {...}` to show how it works. Show us the code (all of it) you are using that produces your error (as mentioned by Sweeper)

Comment: @Sweeper and sumida, I'm really sorry. I'm at baby stage of SwiftUI and please look into the edited code.

Comment: updated my answer with more example code. With this, you should be able to understand how to use `.sorted(by: ...)` and at the same time how to use a `computed` property (itemsSorted) to acheive what you want.

Comment: @sumida, Sorry for the delay. I tried the code but I couldn't. Could you please tell me how can I add in else loop in my given code as I'm using ModelItems. Thank you.

Comment: @sumida, Finally I sorted out as I wanted with your help. Thank you so much for your help. Could you please support me if you have time as I have some more queries regarding coding. Thank you..

Comment: When you post other questions, be sure
  to provide a **simple reproducible code**, that compiles, runs and demonstrates your problems.
This is important, and it makes it much more likely to give you answers that fit your question.